# why there are two monitorexit

Tags: java, synchronization

This is my java source code:

```
public class Father{
     public void  doing(){
     synchronized(this){

  }
}
```

then compile,and run javap -verbose Father.class.Here is output:

```
  public void doing();
descriptor: ()V
flags: ACC_PUBLIC
Code:
  stack=2, locals=3, args_size=1
     0: aload_0
     1: dup
     2: astore_1
     3: monitorenter
     4: aload_1
     5: monitorexit
     6: goto          14
     9: astore_2
    10: aload_1
    11: monitorexit
    12: aload_2
    13: athrow
    14: return
```

why there are two monitorexit.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: The output indicates `locals=3,` but you don't declare 3 local variables but only 1 (`this`). Recompile and try again or show the real source code.

Comment: But the output is that.You can try it.My java version is 8

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never. The monitorenter and monitorexit instructions are designed for capture and release the monitor. The second monitorexit will be used in case you have an exception/error in your synchronized block.